# Is "Ich weiß es nicht, ob es wichtig ist." valid sentence?

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

I know that

> Ich weiß nicht, ob es wichtig ist.

is how it is said.

But if someone writes or says

> Ich weiß es nicht, ob es wichtig ist.

it considered wrong or fine?

Comment: I have some problems due to missing context: *es* represents probably a previously made statement in the first example.  But in the second example there are two *es*, which seem to refer to different issues and no details for their distinction are given.

Comment: For first sentence "es" represents a previously made statement. But for second sentence, the first "es" is more like how "es" is used in this example: "Ich hasse es am Wochenende zu arbeiten."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally "Ich weiß nicht, ob es wichtig ist." is the standard form. Into English the most likely translation is "I do not know whether this is important."

The emphasis form of "Ich weiß es nicht, ob es wichtig ist." is more like "I am not sure / I am uncertain whether this is important."

Both are correct, their meanings differs around the context in spoken / written German and the second form is far more seldom. However both expressions can be encountered in the same context as well. German can be difficult, just a little bit more than other languages.

Comment: Are you sure this is an emphasis form? This strikes me as quite unusual, if not to say it sounds wrong to my ears.

Comment: To me this sounds like something only said in spoken language when trying to restructure the sentence half-way through. Something like "Ich weiß es nicht... \[also] ob es wichtig ist."

Comment: @infinitezero: That matches what I found in the DWDS usage database. My understanding is you use *es* as a placeholder when the clause would be ungrammatical without it, for example: *Es ist wichtig für mich, dass ... .* This doesn't seem to happen much with *ob* clauses, maybe: *Es ist nicht bekannt, ob ... .*

Comment: The context of emphasis comes from speaking German myself. This extra "es" in the first part feels exceptional so in normal conversation this use stresses this "es" in a particular way.

Comment: For me the sentence ist more or less borderline. In the first part, _es_ could be interpreted as an "antecedent" for the second part, but in this case I would prefer _Ich weiß es nicht, ob *das* wichtig ist._ However you can find similar constructions as in the given sentence on the internet. You can find there as well "könnte möglich sein", "etwas für Bauchschmerzen", "in keinster Weise" and many other questionable phrasings. Usually _es_ is referring back to an aforementioned part of the text: _Ob es wirklich wichtig ist? Ich weiß es nicht._

Comment: @Knut Boehnert : I can hardly imagine a stressed "es" except in very special contexts. Two "es" in one sentence is redundat in a certain way, the first one referring to the subordinate clause, the second one referring back to the main clause. It's a circular reference, for me logically unsatisfying.